# A simple $\ell^1$ norm question

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $B$ be a closed subspace of $\ell^1$ such that
$$
B=\{\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^1 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1} x_n = 0\} .
$$
I want to show that there is NO $x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots) \in B$ satisfying $$\|(1,0,0,\cdots) - (x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots)\|_{\ell^1} = 1/2 $$
I have just calculated directly but it seems not to be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $\Lambda\in(\ell^1)^*$ by $$\Lambda x = \sum\frac{n}{n+1}x_n.$$Note that $||\Lambda||=1$. In fact it's clear that $$|\Lambda x|<||x||\quad(x\ne0).$$ If $\Lambda x=0$ then $x\ne e_1$, hence $$\frac12=\Lambda(e_1-x)
<||e_1-x||_1.$$

Comment: I was looking at this, but I had trouble seeing why $\Lambda$ is not norm-attaining.  I imagine it has something to do with the fact that $\|\Lambda\|=\lim_n\frac{n}{n+1}$.  Could you clarify?

Comment: If $x_n\ne0$ then $n/(n+1)|x_n|<|x_n|$; hence $|\sum_j j/(j+1)x_j|<\sum_j|x_j|$.

Comment: @Aweygan Thanks for the comments. In fact I could not understand that the last statement that $1/2 = \Lambda(e_1 - x)$. How does this follow?

Comment: @JohnS $\Lambda(e_1-x)=\Lambda(e_1)-\Lambda(x)=\frac{1}{2}-0$. By definition,  $x$ is in the null space of $\Lambda$, and just calculate $\Lambda(e_1)$.

Comment: @Aweygan Oh I got it thanks a lot!